# How to store the result of remote hive query to a file

Tags: hive, hiveql, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to run a hive query on Google Compute Engine. My Hadoop service is on Google Dataproc.
I submit the hive job using this command -

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --region=my-region --cluster=my-cluster-name -f file.hql > result.txt
```

and

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --region=my-region --cluster=my-cluster-name -e="use test;select * from emp;" > result.txt
```

I expect to see the result of the query in result.txt but this is all I get in the txt file -

```
done: true
driverControlFilesUri: gs://my-gcs-bucket-for-dataproc/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/27f9-f4a5-4df2-a311-e41a92/jobs/ea7ab2164/
driverOutputResourceUri: gs://my-gcs-bucket-for-dataproc/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/1f309-f4a5-4df2-a311-e4182/jobs/eafab0e2164/driveroutput
hiveJob:
queryFileUri: gs://my-gcs-bucket-for-dataproc/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/1ff9-f4a5-4df2-a311-e412/jobs/ea781f64/staging/file.hql
jobUuid: 91db33-ee0e-391b-b46d-37b276
placement:
  clusterName: my-cluster-name
  clusterUuid: my-cluster-uuid
reference:
  jobId: ea7ab0e2164
  projectId: my-project
status:
  state: DONE
  stateStartTime: '2022-02-07T09:33:44.317237Z'
statusHistory:
- state: PENDING
  stateStartTime: '2022-02-07T09:33:16.724561Z'
- state: SETUP_DONE
  stateStartTime: '2022-02-07T09:33:16.762680Z'
- details: Agent reported job success
  state: RUNNING
  stateStartTime: '2022-02-07T09:33:18.403518Z'
yarnApplications:
- name: HIVE-94a5b7-8bc7-4dc9-a016-81ab721
  progress: 1.0
  state: RUNNING
  trackingUrl: http://my-cluster-name:8088/proxy/application_1692_0008/
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the `emp` table empty? If not, the result should be available in the gcloud output.

Comment: emp table is not empty. It has data. I get the output on the console when the gcloud command gets executed but output doesn't get captured in the txt file.

Comment: Try `&> result.txt` to redirect stderr as well?

Comment: It worked. I got the result of the query in the txt file along with everything else I mentioned in this post. I'll just use awk or sed to filter out the result. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I added an answer, could you accept? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query result is in stderr. Try `&> result.txt` to redirect both stdout and stderr, or `2> result.txt` to redirect stderr only.